# On click show one hide all others JS or CSS or "Toggle"?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code:
    http://jsfiddle.net/chris_bentley/21onnz5a/

```
<ul id="header-master-fixed-icon">
<li><a href="#" id="header-master-fixed-search" ></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="header-master-fixed-account"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="header-master-fixed-help"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="header-master-fixed-bag"><span id="header-master-fixed-bag-number">5</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

They all relate to a dropdown that pops down when clicked. What I need to happen is when one is clicked the others close. Right now when you click it opens and then the next opens right on to of the previous. 
All are closed until clicked on.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I can only use JS or CSS per restrictions

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery

```
$('#one_dropbox').click(function()
{
  $('#second_dropbox').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you rajan ks, but where would that go in the code? I tried it and it is not working. Sorry.